# Nexus 4 stuck in boot loop

Tags: updates, nexus-4, boot-loop

Yesterday some guy has changed my `3.5 mm jack` in nexus 4. Old one was broken. After that I could not turned on my phone. I saw infinite boot. I had android 5 in that time.

Today I install `android 4.2.2 (JDQ39)` with help `fastboot`. Nexus 4 has booted now. But there is one problem. If I am updating nexus to `android 4.4` or android 5, I see infinite boot again.

Also I tried to install `CyanogenMod 13`. The problem is same.

How to update my phone to android 5 or cm 13?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems, that the problem is bad position of **rubber gasket** in **proximity sensor**.

https://youtu.be/AZDAIgwbXk4?t=8m22s